# Spring batch to save csv files records in Mongo DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on spring batch which reads record from csv file from one location and save into mongo DB. I want to read the records in particular Object type but while writing it should be in different object type.
Like if I am reading file with obj1 then I want to set obj1 to obj2 and save to DB.
Below is my code.

```
@Bean
    public Job readCSVFileJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("readCSVFileJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step")
                .<FileObj, FileObj>chunk(5)
                .reader(reader(null))
                .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(fileVerificationSkipper())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SkipPolicy fileVerificationSkipper() {
        return new FileVerificationSkipper();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<FileObj> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fullPathFileName']}") String fullPathFileName) {
        FlatFileItemReader<FileObj> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<FileObj>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        try {
            itemReader.setResource(new PathResource(fullPathFileName)); // set resource from a FTP location
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return itemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<FileObj> lineMapper() {
       //code for line mapper this works fine
        return lineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoItemWriter<OBJ2> writer() {
       // in this I want to write in mongo DB with OBJ2 something like below
    repository.save(obj2);
        return writer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an [`ItemProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemProcessor) that transforms `obj1` items to `obj2`. Data transformation is a typical use case for an `ItemProcessor`.